# Needing to find parent zip code of a bunch of missing zip codes in the US

Tags: sql, sql-server, distance, geometry, geography

We're using MapPoint to export zip code / territory combinations. Unfortunately, the export doesn't include PO Box zip codes which mean that we're missing a lot of zip codes

The PO Box zip codes are contained within a parent zip code and so I just need to work out what the parent zip code is for each of the missing zip codes.

I have 2 SQL tables:

- ALL zip codes with Lat/Lng and Geography column. Also has a GeometryShape column
- standard zip codes with Lat/Lng and Geography column.

Couple of ways I was looking to do it...

- either find the closest Geography point to each missing zip code and make the closest one the parent zip (using STDistance)
  OR
- Convert the geometry shape to a geography shape of the standard zips, then use STIntersects to find which shape the missing zip lat/lng belongs to.

Having a bit of bother with this, first time I've worked with geospatial querying in SQL